# What is the correct way to initiate Extjs 6 app without sencha cmd?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Ext.application({
  ....
  // This doesn't do anything 
})

new Ext.Viewport({
  // This throws an error
})
```

I know it's recommended to use Sencha Cmd, but I wanna simplify the workflow as the scripts will be used in other context, so please show the way without Sencha Cmd.

P/S: The application I'm working on undertaking an upgrade from version 3.4 to 6.

Edit: I expect Extjs 6 can be used in this way:

```
<!-- main html -->
<script src='ext-all.js' ></script>

<script src='app-all.js' ></script>
```

As you can see, the way to load application scripts is old school. In `app-all.js`, I tried the approaches above but none worked. A work around I've used is to init a container with width = 100% and height = 100%.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough context.

Comment: I have updated the question. I'm not sure if it makes anything clearer

Comment: What error you get on app launch ?

Comment: No error, just it doesn't do anything. In v3.4 you got `new Ext.Viewport` to init the app for inline script, but I haven't found any equivalent in v6. Using `new Ext.Viewport` does throw an Error though: `Ext.Viewport is not a constructor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve found the soultion. Extjs 6 has class at `Ext.container.Viewport` that will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify a ["mainView"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#cfg-mainView) config in the Ext.application param object like so:

```
Ext.application({
    mainView: 'App.view.main.Main'
});
```

This will create the class you've specified there, and apply a viewport plugin to it.

Or, you can use the ["launch"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.app.Application.html#method-launch) template function, like so:

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('App.view.main.Main');
    }
});
```